# symfony Redirect to an other page after true comparison of request from ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, symfony, redirect

I have a function in my JavaScript that returns data. I would like to send data to my controller and do a test with that data from my js. Then, if true, I want to display another page.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: path,
        data: { s_certifiedNir: a.Patients[0].s_certifiedNir },

        success: function (data) {

           console.log('yooo' + a.Patients[0].s_certifiedNir) ;


        }
        ,
        error: function () {
            alert('ko');
        }

    });
```

Here is my controller :

```
public function getCpsInfosAction(Request $request)
{
    $nir= $request->get('s_certifiedNir');
    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $encoders = array(new XmlEncoder(), new JsonEncoder());
        $normalizers = array(new ObjectNormalizer());
        $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
        $data = $serializer->normalize($nir);
        if ($data=='2550699999999 34')
        {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('test');
        }

        //return new  JsonResponse($data);
    }

}
```

I got ko and There are no registered paths for namespace " DMP".
DMP is the first route of my page.

Comment: I don't think you can redirect from ajax; the controller should just do the check and return the result, and then the JS should do the redirect (ex: window.location)

Comment: i know but the problem i should compare the result of ajaw with an information from the data base so i should pass by the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just set the redirect URL in the response and handle it in your JS?:

```
public function getCpsInfosAction(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        // ...
        if ($data === '2550699999999 34') {
            return new JsonResponse([
                'success'  => true,
                'redirect' => $this->generateUrl('your_route');
            ]);
        }

        return new JsonResponse(['success' => false]); // else..
    }
}
```

Then just run the redirect from JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
    // ...
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.success) {
            window.location.href = data.redirect; // <-- HERE
        }
    },
    // ...
});
```

Comment: it works thank you but how can i send  a lot of inforation , i mean i send an object of data

Comment: @EsanteDev You can "send" whatever you want in your `JsonResponse` like `return new JsonResponse(['success' => true, 'redirect' => $this->genUrl('route'), 'time' => new DateTime(), 'current_item' => $someEntity, 'blah' => 'blah']);` and all of those will be accessible in your JS/jQuery success function via `data.blah` or `data.current_item` etc.  Cheers